# Unicode text represented as u'xxxx instead of Japanese in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I've had many struggles with Unicode in Python over the years as I work with many text files in Japanese, so I'm familiar with using .encode("utf-8") to get Japanese text back into Japanese display from u'xxxx. I am NOT getting any encoding/decoding errors. But text I'm reading from a unicode file, manipulating, then writing back into a new file is being represented as strings of u'xxxx instead of the original Japanese text. I have tried .encode() and .decode() in multiple places, and also not using them at all, every time with the same result. Any suggestions are welcome.

Specifically, I am using the Scrapy library to write a spider that takes text from a file it crawls, extracts bits of text to construct the filename of a new file, and then writes the first div of the HTML file as a string into that new file.

What is even more confusing to me is that the bits of text I'm using to create the filename all render in Japanese, as does the filename itself. Is it because I am using str() on the div that I am getting u'xxxx as the content of my file? Please toward the end of the code to see this line.

Here is my complete code (and please ignore how hacky some of it is):

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    original = 0
    author = "noauthor"
    title = "notitle"
    year = "xxxx"
    publisher = "xxxx"
    typer = "xxxx"
    ispub = 0
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
    if "_" in filename:
        filename = filename.split("_")[0]
        if filename.isdigit():
            title = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()[0].encode("utf-8")
            author = response.xpath("//h2/text()").extract()[0].encode("utf-8")
            ID = filename
            bibliographic_info = response.xpath("//div[2]/text()").extract()
            for subyear in bibliographic_info:
                ispub = 0
                subyear = subyear.encode("utf-8").strip()
                if "初出：" in subyear:
                    publisher = subyear.split("：")[1]
                    original = 1
                    ispub = 1
                if "入力：" in subyear:
                    typer = subyear.split("：")[1]
                if len(subyear) > 1 and (original == 1) and (ispub == 0):
                    counter = 0
                    while counter < len(subyear):
                        if subyear[counter].isdigit():
                            break
                        counter+=1
                    if counter != len(subyear):
                        year = subyear[counter:(counter+4)]
                    original = 0
    body = str(response.xpath("//div[1]/text()").extract())
    new_filename = author + "_" + title + "_" + publisher + "_" + year + "_" + typer + ".html"
    file = open(new_filename, "a")
    file.write(body.encode("utf-8")  
    file.close()
```

Comment: First, you have to show us the actual things you're getting, not just a vague description of them. Where are you printing or writing to a file or whatever, what value are you printing, and what does it look like? Second, this is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's a bunch of code which is probably mostly irrelevant to the problem, and at the same time not complete enough to run.

Comment: Meanwhile, you're doing Unicode almost completely backward. Don't encode things to UTF-8 and then search the UTF-8; keep things in Unicode and search the Unicode, and only encode to UTF-8 at the boundaries (e.g., when writing to a file). And definitely don't use non-Unicode string literals like `"初出："`.

Comment: Finally: "I have tried .encode() and .decode() in multiple places, and also not using them at all" is not a useful way to write or debug code. You have to understand what types you have at each point, and what types you want, and then everything is easy. If you just randomly throw in `encode` and `decode` calls without knowing what you're trying to do, at very best you'll get some code that mostly works that you have no idea how to maintain or extend. Especially in Python 2, where you can call `decode` on a `unicode` and it "works" by encoding to your default codec so has something to decode…

Answer (score 3):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# u'初出' and u'\u521d\u51fa' are different ways to specify *the same* string
assert u'初出' == u'\u521d\u51fa'
#XXX don't mix Unicode and bytes!!!
assert u'初出' != '初出' and u'初出' != '\u521d\u51fa'
```

Don't use `str()` at all with a Unicode string as an argument, use the explicit `.encode()` instead.
Do not call `.encode()`, `.decode()` unless necessary; use Unicode sandwich instead:

- decode bytes that you receive from outside world into Unicode
- keep it Unicode inside your script
- encode into bytes at the end to save to a file, send over a network.

Both the first and the last step might be implicit i.e., your program might only see Unicode text.

Note, these are three different things:

- the way a string looks like in the source code when you specify it using a string literal (unicode escapes, source code encoding, raw string literals)
- the content of the string
- how it looks like if you print it (`repr()`, 'backslashreplace' error handler)

If you see `u'...'` in the output; it means that at some point `repr(unicode_string)` is called. It may be implicit e.g., via `print([unicode_string])` because `repr()` is called on items of the list while it is converted to string.

```
print(u'\u521d\u51fa')       # -> 初出 #NOTE: no u'', \u..
print(repr(u'\u521d\u51fa')) # -> u'\u521d\u51fa'
```